# Create a list of lists of possible combinations

Tags: python

I have a list, which contains the following items:

```
initl = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and a `stepsize`, which is `stepsize = 0.05`. Each value in the list is allowed to change by the `stepsize` either up or down. What I would like to create is a list of lists, which contains all combinations of up, down or initial values, e.g. like so:

```
result_list = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1.05, 2, 3, 4], [0.95, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2.05, 3, 4], ...]
```

The order of combinations within the list doesn't matter.

I came up with this:

```
import itertools


initl = [1, 2, 3, 4]
stepsize = 0.05

lu = [i + stepsize for i in initl]
ld = [i - stepsize for i in initl]

l_map = list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=4))

result_list = []

for i in l_map:
    l_new = []
    for pos, j in enumerate(i):
        if j == 0:
            l_new.append(ld[pos])
        elif j == 1:
            l_new.append(initl[pos])
        else:
            l_new.append(lu[pos])
   result_list.append(l_new)
```

which produces the desired output. List length: 3^4 = 81.
But I wonder if there's a better approach to this. The nested for loop in particular seems clunky to me here. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Thanks guys for the amazing answers. I particularly liked the recursive generator approach by Grzegorz Skibinski. Other's answers were similar to each other, but I decided to acccept Adam.Er8's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had the right idea, essentially implementing [`numpy.choose`](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) yourself, for a 3-choice case.

You can simplify using `itertools.product` directly on a list of which contains a tuple of all options for each value, like this:

```py
import itertools

initl = [1, 2, 3, 4]
stepsize = 0.05

prod_seed = [(i, i+stepsize, i-stepsize) for i in initl]
result_list = list(itertools.product(*prod_seed))

print(result_list)
print(len(result_list))
```

Output:

```
[(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4.05), (1, 2, 3, 3.95), ....]
81
```

Comment: You are right, the latter part is essentially `np.choose`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
def getComb(arr, step, res=[]):
    if(len(arr)==1):
        for el in [-step, 0, step]:
            yield res+[arr[0]+el]
    else:
        for el in [-step, 0, step]:
            yield from getComb(arr[1:], step, res+[arr[0]+el])
```

For your input data outputs:

```py
>>> for el in getComb(initl, stepsize): print(el)

[0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95]
[0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 4]
[0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 4.05]
[0.95, 1.95, 3, 3.95]
[0.95, 1.95, 3, 4]
...
[1.05, 2.05, 3, 4]
[1.05, 2.05, 3, 4.05]
[1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 3.95]
[1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4]
[1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05]
```

Comment: Very interesting approach! Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

You could try a list comprehension like the following, `zip`ing the `product`s with `initl`:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> initl = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> step = [-0.05, 0, 0.05]
>>> [[x+d for x, d in zip(initl, p)] for p in product(step, repeat=len(initl))]
[[0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95],
 [0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 4],
 ...
 [1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05]]
>>> len(_)
81
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. All you need to do is transposing the matrix consisting of the 3 (4 lengthed) lists, so that *itertools.product* can pick for each element from `[elem[i] - stepsize, elem[i], elem[i] + stepsize]`. That is done by the *zip* function.

> ```py
> >>> import itertools as it
> >>>
> >>> initl = [1, 2, 3, 4]
> >>> stepsize = 0.05
> >>>
> >>> lo = [elem - stepsize for elem in initl]
> >>> hi = [elem + stepsize for elem in initl]
> >>> lo, hi
> ([0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95], [1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05])
> >>>
> >>> list(it.product(*zip(lo, initl, hi)))
> [(0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95), (0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 4), (0.95, 1.95, 2.95, 4.05), (0.95, 1.95, 3, 3.95), (0.95, 1.95, 3, 4), (0.95, 1.95, 3, 4.05), (0.95, 1.95, 3.05, 3.95), (0.95, 1.95, 3.05, 4), (0.95, 1.95, 3.05, 4.05), (0.95, 2, 2.95, 3.95), (0.95, 2, 2.95, 4), (0.95, 2, 2.95, 4.05), (0.95, 2, 3, 3.95), (0.95, 2, 3, 4), (0.95, 2, 3, 4.05), (0.95, 2, 3.05, 3.95), (0.95, 2, 3.05, 4), (0.95, 2, 3.05, 4.05), (0.95, 2.05, 2.95, 3.95), (0.95, 2.05, 2.95, 4), (0.95, 2.05, 2.95, 4.05), (0.95, 2.05, 3, 3.95), (0.95, 2.05, 3, 4), (0.95, 2.05, 3, 4.05), (0.95, 2.05, 3.05, 3.95), (0.95, 2.05, 3.05, 4), (0.95, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05), (1, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95), (1, 1.95, 2.95, 4), (1, 1.95, 2.95, 4.05), (1, 1.95, 3, 3.95), (1, 1.95, 3, 4), (1, 1.95, 3, 4.05), (1, 1.95, 3.05, 3.95), (1, 1.95, 3.05, 4), (1, 1.95, 3.05, 4.05), (1, 2, 2.95, 3.95), (1, 2, 2.95, 4), (1, 2, 2.95, 4.05), (1, 2, 3, 3.95), (1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4.05), (1, 2, 3.05, 3.95), (1, 2, 3.05, 4), (1, 2, 3.05, 4.05), (1, 2.05, 2.95, 3.95), (1, 2.05, 2.95, 4), (1, 2.05, 2.95, 4.05), (1, 2.05, 3, 3.95), (1, 2.05, 3, 4), (1, 2.05, 3, 4.05), (1, 2.05, 3.05, 3.95), (1, 2.05, 3.05, 4), (1, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05), (1.05, 1.95, 2.95, 3.95), (1.05, 1.95, 2.95, 4), (1.05, 1.95, 2.95, 4.05), (1.05, 1.95, 3, 3.95), (1.05, 1.95, 3, 4), (1.05, 1.95, 3, 4.05), (1.05, 1.95, 3.05, 3.95), (1.05, 1.95, 3.05, 4), (1.05, 1.95, 3.05, 4.05), (1.05, 2, 2.95, 3.95), (1.05, 2, 2.95, 4), (1.05, 2, 2.95, 4.05), (1.05, 2, 3, 3.95), (1.05, 2, 3, 4), (1.05, 2, 3, 4.05), (1.05, 2, 3.05, 3.95), (1.05, 2, 3.05, 4), (1.05, 2, 3.05, 4.05), (1.05, 2.05, 2.95, 3.95), (1.05, 2.05, 2.95, 4), (1.05, 2.05, 2.95, 4.05), (1.05, 2.05, 3, 3.95), (1.05, 2.05, 3, 4), (1.05, 2.05, 3, 4.05), (1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 3.95), (1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4), (1.05, 2.05, 3.05, 4.05)]
> ```